# How to add a value from a dict to a list only if the dict has a specific key?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say I have a class `Node`, with attributes `left`, `right`, `val`. Then suppose we have `internal` and `leaf`, where `leaf` has `None` for `left` and `right`. Then iterating through `my_list = [internal, leaf]`, I only want to add the child nodes to an array only if they exist, so I would do something like

```
[x.left if x.left is not None for x in my_list]
```

Is something like this possible? When I try this I get a invalid syntax error

Comment: you can use `[x.left for x in my_list if hasattr(x, "left")]`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! You need to switch the ordering of the `for` and `if` clauses:

```py
[x.left for x in my_list if x.left is not None]
```